# X axe on Gnuplot 4.6

Tags: linux, gnuplot

I've this data :

```
2020-04;26.94
2020-05;26.92
2020-06;26.89
2020-07;27.01
2020-08;26.73
2020-09;26.72
```

I use this gnuplot script ( I'm bound to use the **4.6** version of Gnuplot ) :

```
reset

FILE = "LINEARFIT.txt"
set datafile separator ";"
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%d"
set format x "%Y\n%d"

plot FILE u (StartDate=timecolumn(1)):0 index 0 every ::0:0:0

EndDate = strptime("%Y-%d","2020-20")
f(x) = a*(x-StartDate) + b
FIT_LIMIT = 1e-8
fit f(x) FILE u (timecolumn(1)):2 via a,b

set terminal png truecolor size 900,520 background rgb "#eff1f0"
set output "/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx.png"
set xrange[StartDate:EndDate]
set grid xtics, ytics
set yrange[0:30]
set format y "%g"
myLabel(n) = sprintf("%g",n)

plot FILE u (timecolumn(1)):2 w lp pt 7 lc rgb "red" notitle, \
'' using 1:2:(myLabel($2)) w labels offset 0,-0.5 notitle, \
      f(x) ti "linear fit with extrapolation"
```

And the output is :
[image]

Can you tell me why, on the x axe, the values are displayed "**Two by two**" : 2020-**04**,2020-**06**,2020-**08**,2020-**10**,2020-**12**,2020-**014**,2020-**16**,2020-**18**,2020-**20**... While I want 2020-**04**,2020-**05**,2020-**07**,2020-**08**,2020-**09**,2020-**10**,2020-**11**,2020-**12** ....

Could you help me ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

> X axes on Gnuplot 4.6

Your files are OK with "all dates" : The RHEL 7, CentOS 7 `gnuplot-4.6.2`, when the x axis is edited to "2020-15" (which is the maximum setting for not showing only "every second date setting")

```
EndDate = strptime("%Y-%d","2020-15")
```

[image]

The result / the gnuplot behaviour is exactly the same with e.g. gnuplot-**5**.2.2 .

Other example, gnuplot x labels "time %m.%y settings" https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/%5Bgnuplot%5D-ugly-labels-4175670549/#post6096000