# Problem with the starting date and end date on my script gnuplot 4.6

Tags: gnuplot

First of all, I'm bound to use the **4.6 version** of gnuplot on my server.

I've these data :

```
2019-10;27.39
2019-11;27.39
2019-12;27.54
2020-01;27.13
2020-02;27.01
2020-03;26.93
2020-04;26.46
2020-05;26.63
```

And I've this gnuplot script :

```
reset

FILE = "LINEARFIT.txt"
set datafile separator ";"
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%d"
set format x "%Y\n%d"

plot FILE u (StartDate=timecolumn(1)):1 index 0 every ::0:0:0

EndDate = strptime("%Y-%d","2020-12")
f(x) = a*(x-StartDate) + b
FIT_LIMIT = 1e-8
fit f(x) FILE u (timecolumn(1)):2 via a,b

set terminal png truecolor size 620,420 background rgb "#eff1f0"
set output "/xxx/xxx/xxx/data.png"
set xrange[StartDate:EndDate]
set grid xtics, ytics
set yrange[0:30]
#set xtics rotate by 90
set format y "%g"
myLabel(n) = sprintf("%g",n)

plot FILE u (timecolumn(1)):2 w lp pt 7 lc rgb "red" notitle, \
'' using 1:2:(myLabel($2)) w labels offset 0,-0.5 notitle, \
      f(x) ti "linear fit with extrapolation"
```

This script works well if I use the data of the current year ( all the lines in data which starts by 2020 ) :
[image]

But I would like to include the 3 lines from 2019. But if I keep all my data ( 2019+2020 ), I've this result :
[image]

And if I want to extend this graph to the next year by modifying the end date 2020-12 by 2021-01, I've this result :
[image]

Someone to tell me why I've this result ?

Comment: are you sure your timeformat should be `%Y-%d` (Year-Day), instead of `%Y-%m` (Year-Month)?

Comment: Indeed, this is the error in the script. I didn't see it ! Thanks !

Comment: well, can happen... ;-). The same in your other question... https://stackoverflow.com/q/61340972/7295599

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of not letting this questions appear unanswerered:

Your timeformat should be `%Y-%d` (Year-Day), instead of `%Y-%m` (Year-Month).